# Molex PicoBlade current rating confusing

Tags: connector, datasheet, terminal, contact, current-rating

It seems there are confliction in specifications of PicoBlade for current rating.

From the [MolexPicoBlade Connector System datasheet](https://www.molex.com/content/dam/molex/molex-dot-com/en_us/pdf/datasheets/987651-3691.pdf),

[image]

I assume that the current values in table is per circuit value.
So, with 26AWG 2-circuit, I can transfer 2.5A for each circuit.

On the other hand, from the [datasheet of female crimp terminal for PicoBlade 050079-8000](https://www.mouser.kr/datasheet/2/276/0500798000_CRIMP_TERMINALS-701981.pdf),

[image]

Current rating is specified as 1A per contact. It is same for male crimp terminal too.

Now I am confused. If the crimp terminal allows only 1A, how can a PicoBlade connector can transfer 2.5A?

Comment: Is there a different crimp terminal available for the same connector perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> with 26AWG 2-circuit, I can transfer 2.5A for each circuit.

Correct.

> Current rating is specified as 1A per contact

The [product page](https://www.molex.com/en-us/products/part-detail/500798001) for the 50079 contact (26 AWG) only specifies the maximum current for the maximum number of contacts in a housing: 15. It doesn't specify the current based on the number of contacts in a housing.

But if you open the [detailed spec sheet for the 50079 contact](https://www.molex.com/content/dam/molex/molex-dot-com/products/automated/en-us/productspecificationpdf/510/51021/510211110-PS-000.pdf?inline) and scroll down to  section 4.3, you will see that it says 2.5 A for 26 AWG, 25 C, and only two current-carrying circuits.

[image: Spec sheet]